# Let external library draw onto a WPF-panel?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have quite a simple C#-application. It consists of a main window which contains an embedded wf:Panel "DrawArea". The HWND of this panel (DrawArea.Handle) is handed over to an external DLL which uses it to put some (native, non-WPF) GUI elements on it.

This external DLL is also a native one, so no relation to .NET/C#/WPF. My problem: this application worked properly, means the GUI-elements of the external DLL have been visible in my WPF-application perfectly. Now, about one year later I tried the same application but with no success. None of the external GUI-elements are visible, nothing is shown on my wf:Panel.

Neither the external DLL nor my application have been changed, so I suspect there is a problems somewhere else (may be some Windows-update that happenend in between?). Any ideas if something important was changed in Windows?

Or is there anything else I could look at in order to ensure the external DLL again can make use of my wf:Panel?

Comment: Your question sounds too broad, please add some details - logs, errors, source code, otherwise it's hard to understand where is the problem exactly

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski the question contains the complete description of the application, it really isn't more than a Window with a wf:Panel where the panels Handle is handed over to this 3rd party DLL which uses it for drawing WinAPI GUI elements on it. Where can I find some WPF logs which may be useful?

Comment: There is no specific WPF, afaik. I'm asking about your application logs, which is controlled by you or other developers

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski my own application has no log as it consists of a few lines of code only that call this 3rd party DLL. The DLL itself returns "OK", so from its point of view everything is fine, means it received a valid HWND from my application and has used it for creating the GUI elements successfully. That's why I have the feeling something more basic suppresses these GUI elements now